# AWS Signed Cookies in an IFrame?

Tags: amazon-s3, iframe, amazon-cloudfront, samesite

Is it possible to support cookies in an IFrame that won't be broken by some of the recent cookie security improvements? The IFrame is embedded on arbitrary domains that we don't control. Other than the initial request URI being passed, we don't care about any special message passing or cross domain access.

Context: an app I've inherited serves authenticated S3 content in an IFrame to users. The content is proxied by CloudFront, leaning on their Signed Cookies feature to authenticate the initial HTML page, as well as every other asset (CSS, JS, images, etc.) that might be on the page. The cookie is generated/set after a successful auth handshake.

Recently, the move towards blocking third party cookies has broken this model. Users need to downgrade their security settings, and this will flat out stop working soon.

Short of a larger architectural change, is there a way to configure the cookies or CF to work within an IFrame, embedded on domains we don't control? My assumption is that this model is fundamentally broken now, but I wanted to triple check before reaching for a larger architectural change.

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I was using CloudFront signed cookies so that requests to MPEG playlists (.m3u8) by `<audio>` and `<video>` elements could access all the necessary segmented files. My web app runs within an iframe, and I noticed Safari wasn't transmitting the cookies in the file requests. Kinda silly, especially since CloudFront uses secure HTTP cookies.. so Safari is really being kind of paranoid.

I don't have a solution yet, though I think CloudFront signed URLs are the only direction to go from here.